# Why am I getting the error The source profile "default" must have credentials using Boto3 in Docker?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, boto3, aws-cli

I have a `dockerfile`:

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.1.2-python3.8

ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/"

ADD ./aws/credentials /home/airflow/.aws/credentials
ADD ./aws/config /home/airflow/.aws/config

RUN pip install -r requirements.pip
```

And a `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  webserver:
    image: airflow2
    command: webserver
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8080/health" ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - ./airflow.env
    container_name: webserver
    volumes:
      - ./database_utils:/database_utils
  scheduler:
    image: sch-airflow2
    command: scheduler
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD-SHELL", 'airflow jobs check --job-type SchedulerJob --hostname "$${HOSTNAME}"' ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    container_name: scheduler
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - ./airflow.env
    volumes:
      volumes:
      - ./database_utils:/database_utils
    depends_on:
      - webserver
```

When running an script that uses boto3 to connect to s3 it works fine. The issue here is that I am adding the credentials to the image which is a bad practice. Then I delete this line from the `dockerfile`:

```
ADD ./aws/credentials /home/airflow/.aws/credentials
```

And I add this in the `docker-compose` volume section:

```
- ./aws:/home/airflow/.aws
```

If I run the script now it fails with:

```
botocore.exceptions.InvalidConfigError: The source profile "default" must have credentials.
```

I understant the error and I checked that credentials are provided in the docker container:

```
aws configure list
```

[image]

It seems fine, so I don't get it why it returns the error.
I also tried setting up the ENV variables in the `./airflow.env`:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=XXXXXXXXX
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

The only way that I achieve it working is with the `ADD` in the dockerfile.

Comment: What do you have in your `~/.aws/config` file. Maybe that references the profile in your credentials file? Remove the config file if you can and it should use the default credential chain

Comment: It sounds like somewhere in a config you are hard coding the profile to the name "default". otherwise, env variables should work fine

Comment: @jordanm yes in the config file i have before the profiles:

[default]
region = eu-west-1
output = json

The goal is to set the base region and output format

Answer (score 3):

Something *somewhere* is specifying the default profile to be used.

This can happen because:

- You specify `--profile default` as a command line parameter
- You have an environment variable of [`AWS_PROFILE`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html#envvars-list) with value of `default`
- Your `~/.aws/credentials` contains `[default]`
- Your `~/.aws/config` file contains `[default]`

The above, ordered in terms of [precedence](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkref/latest/guide/creds-config-files.html#overview-cred-provider-order), tell AWS to use the `default` profile.

**Double-check the default profile is not being referenced in any of the above** (most likely your config or credentials file).

Comment: you are right, default is used in the config file. The issue here is I had it to specify region and output. I should use instead Env variables, and delete this lines from config?

[default]
region = eu-west-1
output = json

Comment: Yes use ENV variables as that would be easier :)

Comment: great, will try :) Thanks!

Comment: Let me know if it works :)

Comment: it's not working. I delete it and it gives:

`Partial credentials found in assume-role, missing: source_profile or credential_source`



Then I added source_profile with the same name, example:

`[profile name]
region=eu-west-1
role_arn=arn
source_profile=name`

It returns: `Infinite loop in credential configuration detected. Attempting to load from profile name which has already been visited. Visited profiles: ['name']`

Comment: Once you set env vars, you don't need to copy over credentials - either stick to a cred file or use env vars

Comment: this setup is not in the credentials as I am not copying it anymore. It's in the config while which I need for the roles.

Comment: I added this in the config file `credential_source=Environment` and still failing. It returns: Error when retrieving credentials from Environment: `No credentials found in credential_source referenced in profile name`. So it seems like it doenst find the `env` variables, despite printing them in the docker container and seeing the correct value I set up on `env` file.